# Update Listview in Fragment , based on activity result . No result found anywhere

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, dialog, android-actionbar

I have an activity and a fragment
In my activity i have button in my action bar ,on button click a dialog box is popup , in that i have a listview.
If i select any item from that list , that data goes to fragment , and based on that data from activity my fragment listview should be shown

e.g. if i select Technology , technology id =1 should pass in my query parameter and based on that my fragment listview should appear.
everytime i select different item from list my fragment listview should be updated.

But my problem is that i am not getting any data in fragment and my list is not getting updated

Mainactivity.java

```
 @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuItem actionViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.miActionButton);
            // Retrieve the action-view from menu
            View v = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(actionViewItem);
            // Find the button within action-view
            Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCustomAction);
            // Handle button click here

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

            Dialog dialog = null;

            switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
                dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
                dialog.setTitle("Select Category");

                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    }
                });

                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                // Prepare ListView in dialog
                dialog_ListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
                dialog_ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        // i = (int) parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);

                        category_name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        Log.d("category name", category_name);


                        if(category_name.equals("a"))
                        {
                            cat_id=1;

                        }
                        if(category_name.equals("b"))
                        {
                            cat_id=2;
                        }
                        if(category_name.equals("c"))
                        {
                            cat_id=3;
                        }
                        if(category_name.equals("d"))
                        {
                            cat_id=4;
                        }
                        if(category_name.equals("e"))
                        {
                            cat_id=5;
                        }
                        if(category_name.equals("f"))
                        {
                            cat_id=6;
                        }

                         Log.d("id",""+cat_id);

                        dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
                    }

                });

                break;
            }

            return dialog;
        }


    public int getMyData() {
            return cat_id;
        }
```

Fragment.java :

```
 public String param;
        public String url;
        public int cat_id;


        Mainactivity activity = (Mainactivity) getActivity();
            int myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();

            cat_id = myDataFromActivity;
            Log.d("Category_id", "" + cat_id);


            Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                param = "?cat_id=" + cat_id;

                //URL is fake , original url is working fine.
                url = "http://www.abbcd.com/xyz/webservices/data/getAllData.php"
                        + param;

                map1.put("url", url);

                new MultiPartRequester(mainActivity, map1,
                        NetUtils.RequestCode.GET_ALL_DATA,
                        this).execute();
```

Updated Part :

```
@Override
    public void updateFragmentList(int catId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        param = "?cat_id=" + catId;

        url = "http://www.abbcd.com/xyz/webservices/data/getAllData.php"+ param;

        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("url", url);

        new MultiPartRequester(mainActivity, map1,
                NetUtils.GET_DATA, this)
                .execute();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code of passing data to `Fragment`?

Comment: public int getMyData() {
            return cat_id;
        }

Comment: in which function you are calling these lines ? `Mainactivity activity = (Mainactivity) getActivity();
            int myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good approach for communication between `Activity` and `Fragment` is `Listeners`. When you want to update fragment, use the listener and update the fragment. Create the interface in `MainActivity`

**Listener**

```
public interface FragmentListener {
        void updateFragmentList(int catId);
}
```

Implement in `Fragment` as

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.FragmentListener
```

then in `onActivityCreated` of Fragment

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFragmentListener(this);
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public void setFragmentListener(FragmentListener listener)
    {

            this.fragmentListener = listener;

    }

public void sendDataToFragment(int catId) {
      this.fragmentListener.updateFragmentList(catId);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Sending data to fragment using `this.fragmentListener.updateFragmentList(catId);`, create the method in `Fragment` as ``

```
public void updateFragmentList(int catId){
       //Here update your listview with cat id
}
```

Comment: what is this.fragmentListener;

Comment: and how to pass cat_id from activity to fragment.means data ?

Comment: Create global variable in `MainActivity` as `FragmentListener fragmentListener`

Comment: call MainActivity function sendDataToFragment() when you select the dialog item

Comment: how could i get data in fragment ?

Comment: thank u bro..now i am passing parameters and it is loading... but my list is not getting updated

Comment: Show your function how you are updating.

Comment: in this function, you haven't changed any `ListView` item. i think you should do something like this with new catId as `yourListViewVariable.getItemAtPosition(catId)` etc and then `yourListViewVariable.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: new MultiPartRequester(mainActivity, map1,
                NetUtils.GET_DATA, this)
                .execute();.. i am getting list of json ..

Comment: y do i need getItemAtPosition ?

Comment: You getting list of json in which function? And then where are you updating `ListView`?

Comment: from my query , i am getting specific data from cat_id..  but my list is not updating.. list remains same

Comment: updating part is what i am not getting. where should i update my list

Comment: Where you Receive the result of asynctask `new MultiPartRequester(mainActivity, map1, NetUtils.GET_DATA, this) .execute();` Send that list in Fragment and then add all list in ListView as `yourListViewVariable.clear();yourListViewVariable.addAll(yourNewList)`

Comment: send me your skype id

Comment: great answer it's saved my day

Comment: Wow. This is what I have been looking for 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

use static global variable in activity

```
public static int cat_id = 0;
```

---

access `cat_id` in fragment like below

```
 Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                param = "?cat_id=" + activity.cat_id;
```

---

or do below changes in your `getMyData` method

```
public int getMyData() { 
return cat_id; 
}
```

---

**EDITED:**

another approach finally work, call your fragment method from activity ans pass `cat_id` in method. *instead of `ExampleFragment` use your fragment name.*

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.mymethod(cat_id);
```

Comment: `static` `global` variables is not a good approach and we should avoid using un-necessary making of `static` variables. Furthermore, this will not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Again, we should not use unless and util there is intense need because multiple threads can create problems.

Comment: i am using this in dialog  getMyData(), but data is not passing

Comment: I have just given example, My point is to provide the good and optimal solution here.

Comment: I want to pass list item data from activity to fragment , and from that i want to update my list

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha Parmar.. wht is R.id.example_fragment ?

Comment: use your fragment id whatever defined in your activity layout(+id/fragment).

Comment: in my fragment activity only listview is  there .. and no id

Comment: add your activity layout(R.layout.???) file code & fragment(R.layout.???) layout file code in question